# Adding two date stamps into a single SSRS expression/cell

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, server-side-rendering

This is all done in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

So I have a large data set that contains Work orders and then their 'type/craft'. Each craft is then broken down into each row so that you can see how many work orders are still open in the certain craft. At the top of the page, It list, WO's 1-2 Past Due,  WO's 3-5 Past Due, WO's 6-10 Past Due... etc, till you reach 30 days+

I then have an expression inserted that will tell you what date the 1-2 days is... However, I am having trouble making the expression value be 2 dates or an in between date.... For example, I have =DateAdd("d", -1, Now) inserted which will give me the date from 1 day back, however, I would ALSO like it to show 2 days back.... So instead of ONLY saying 6/13/2018... it would say 6/12/2018 to 6/13/2018

I guess I could go back and edit my SQL code to automatically do the dates, however I thought it would be easier to use the report system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want your expression to be something like this:

```
=DateAdd("d", -2, Today()) & " to " & DateAdd("d", -1, Today())
```

If you need the time as well you would want to use `Now` instead of `Today`, but based on your question it seems you are only interested in the dates, so this should return exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is how you'd write it but I highly recommend pulling the date stamps with your query that way you always know that the dates match the data. Add a column to your query for the header.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for that help. Something so simple, is always the hardest. And I plan on adding it into my query eventually, but this will do for this month!